# Using lambda function to switch between different functions in python gives TypeError if invalid function name is given with argument

Tags: python, function, lambda, switch-statement, typeerror

I recently learned lambda functions and switch case and I'm playing with them to understand better. Here, I'm trying to use lambda function to switch between different functions in python like the following

```
def fn_a(x,y):
    return (x+y) * 2
def fn_b(x,y=0):
    return (x+y) * 3

def switch(case):
    return {
        "a":fn_a,
        "b":fn_b,
    }.get(case, lambda: case + " Not Available")

print(switch("a")(2,3))
print(switch("b")(2))
print(switch("c")())

>>> 10
>>> 6
>>> c Not Available
```

The above works as expected. But if I give `print(switch("c")(50))`, I get `TypeError: switch.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`. What should I do to make this work and why? Is there a better way to make all the 4 print statements work?

I tried to use lambda and switch statements to switch between functions but I'm unable to make all the mentioned 4 print statements to work.

Comment: The lambda needs to take parameters.

Comment: If you're going to switch between functions like this, they should all take the same number of parameters, since the caller has no way of knowing that it should pass different numbers of arguments depending on the `switch()` argument.

Comment: You could also use `lambda *args:` so it can be called with any number of arguments.

Comment: I was just playing to see if I can give different set of parameters to different functions. But thank you very much. I'll keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the lambda function to take any number of arguments and return `Not Available` when a case is not available.

```
def switch(case):
    return {
        "a": fn_a,
        "b": fn_b,
    }.get(case, lambda *args: case + " Not Available")
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to lambdas! Your lambda in question is missing an argument. You can make it handle zero or more arguments using the `*args` feature like this

```
lambda *args: case + " Not Available"
```

This will give the expected value

```
10
6
c Not Available
c Not Available
```